# Add cols in grid from variable with scss

Tags: sass

Is it possible to make number of cols in grid-template-columns from a variable?

I have a variable $num-of-cols: 5; That I use to make classes whit scss and it works fine, but I also want to use the same variable to make cols for grid-template-columns. 
Like: grid-template-columns: [col-1] $width-cols [col-2] $width-cols [col-3] $width-cols [col-4] $width-cols [col-5] $width-cols [col-6]; 
$width-cols should be calculatet 100%/$num-of-cols-$grid-gutter-width.
(The names is important and goes from 1 up till $num-of-cols).

```
$grid-gutter-width: 1rem;
$num-of-cols: 5;
$width-cols: calc(100%/#{$num-of-cols} - #{$grid-gutter-width});
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: $grid-gutter-width;
    padding: $grid-gutter-width;
    padding-right: 0;
    grid-template-columns: [col-1] $width-cols [col-2] $width-cols [col-3] $width-cols [col-4] $width-cols [col-5] $width-cols [col-6];
    grid-template-rows: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mixin (or a function) – like:

**SCSS**

```
$grid-gutter-width: 1rem;
$num-of-cols: 5;
$width-cols: calc(100%/#{$num-of-cols} - #{$grid-gutter-width});
@mixin grid-template-columns {
    $columns: [col-1],;  // note trailing comma indicates list  
    @for $i from 2 through $num-of-cols + 1 {
        $columns: append($columns, $width-cols [col-#{$i}], space);
    }
    grid-template-columns: $columns;
}



.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: $grid-gutter-width;
    padding: $grid-gutter-width;
    padding-right: 0;
    @include grid-template-columns; // <= include 
    grid-template-rows: auto;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-right: 0;
  grid-template-columns: [col-1] calc(100%/5 - 1rem) [col-2] calc(100%/5 - 1rem) [col-3] calc(100%/5 - 1rem) [col-4] calc(100%/5 - 1rem) [col-5] calc(100%/5 - 1rem) [col-6];
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I was on the right track but had missed the append function.